# adb doesn't detect android device - vodafone 845

Tags: android, adb

I am developing android app on windows xp and have vodafone 845 phone. I can run my app on emulator in Eclipse.
My problem is that I can't get adb to detect the real device. I found below link but it was for linux.

http://www.newtondev.com/2011/01/21/getting-adb-to-list-your-android-vodafone-845-huawei-u8120-and-get-debugging-working/

Did anyone had luck on windows xp with this phone?

Thanks
Bob

Comment: did enable development usb debugging needs to be enabled on the phone in the settings. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Answer (score 0):

Adb comes with android SDK.
You dont need to download it .
just run `adb devices` ,keeping adb in your classpath.

Comment: Tanmay, please read my description again. I have latest SDK installed of course. When I run my app on emulator, "adb devices" gives me a correct response like "emulator-5554   device", but it gives me an empty list for a real device(vodafone 845) connected.
Regards Bob

Comment: My problem solved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801793/cant-install-windows-usb-driver-vodafone-845