# can't install windows usb driver - vodafone 845

Tags: android

My environment is: windows xp sp3, eclipse, all available software installed using SDK Manager.

Following Android developer site's guide, I could write and run hello world app on Android 2.3 emulator. Then I wanted to see if I could run my app on a real device - vodafone 845 (huawei U8120?) in my case. Here I stuck for two days now trying to install windows usb driver for my device. When I connect my device through usb with Debug setting On, windows keeps to ackowledge it as usb mass storage. On Device Manager, I tried Update Driver, selected C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\google-usb_driver\android_winusb.inf file. it complained like:

"The specified location does not contain information about your hardware"

It's probably because of missing manufacturer/product information (VID_12D1&PID_1031) in inf file, right?

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html site lists supported devices and says that any additional devices will require Windows drivers provided by the hardware manufacturer but so far I couldn't any information.

I guess many developers are facing this issue with their own devices that is not supported by Android SDK and I wonder how they overcome this issue - especially for vodafone 845 device.

Thanks in advance

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=857948) states that the USB drivers are included on the phone.  Once the phone is connected as a USB mass storage device, browse the contents and look for the driver installer.  If you have deleted it or are using a custom ROM you may need to search for the drivers on [google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vodafone+845+usb+driver).

PS This isn't really a hardware support site.

Comment: Setup.exe on the phone did the job and "adb devices" shows me a device now "?       device". Thanks, Dave. Bob

Answer (score 1):

Yes this works like charm. Everything is located on the sd card. There are some weird things though: 
 - You can't to choose, if you want to mount the your phone as storage, on other phones you can.
 - For us the install did not work at first, only the second time.